# Add IntelliJ files to gitignore

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, gitignore

Below my .gitingore file. Why am I seeing see idea directory and myProj.iml on IntelliJ commit changes dialog?
They shouldn't be there since I add them to .gitignore file
What am I missing?

```
*.class

*.log

*.ctxt

.mtj.tmp/

*.jar
*.war
*.nar
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*

.idea/
/out/
target/
myProj.iml
```

Comment: Are you still seeing them after a commit (for your next one)?

Comment: I seeing them when I right click on the project root on the project tree on top-left of the page -> Git -> Commit Directory

Comment: My question was have you committed since you changed the gitignore?

Comment: Am I committed what ?
This is not new project I commited and pushed a lot of times

Comment: Have you made a commit *after* you added the 'IntelliJ' files to gitignore?

Comment: you means commit to the idea folder and to the iml file?
no. I didn't commit them